# System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath) does not create a folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, system.io.directory

I would like to ask if there is something wrong with this code? Because it does not create a folder if the folder does not exist.

```
    Dim folderPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Reading/")

    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
    End If
```

Comment: Run your app as administrator permission .

Comment: @Mr.AF still does not work

Comment: print folderpath and show what's your folder path

Comment: Never run a web site with administrative permissions. Also, it is a bad idea to give it permission to write to the same directory as the web site is in. It would be better to have a subdirectory for it to create more directories in. So, manually create a subdirectorory of your web site with a suitable name, say "Storage" and give the IIS_IUSRS account write permission to it. Then you can use `Dim folderPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/Storage/Reading")`, and there is no need to check if it exists because CreateDirectory does that for you.